# Is there any on select event for select for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, onchange

ok I've got a dropdown menu, and I use

```
$('select.small').change ...
```

It has a couple of options, the problem though, when I select the first option - nothing happens - because it is already selected. Is there any way to make it happen?

So far I was using an additional empty option, which was selected by default and did nothing, but now I've got to use this first and empty option for cleanout, so I just can't add an additional default and empty option.

Comment: Why not leave the first one selected and fire your change callback when the page loads? Then it won't need to fire if you re-select the first option.

Comment: If the first option is already selected, couldn't you do what needs to be done for that option when loading the page rather than waiting until the user tries to selected that option? Wouldn't that be more appropriate since the user might simply see the default and leave it alone?

Comment: Technically, if you're opening the drop down box and selecting the first entry then you're not really selecting anything. You (the programmer) already know what the default selected option is and so you shouldn't have to be prompted when someone chooses it. Similarly people are unlikely to come to your site, see a drop down box with the option they want already chosen and yet open the select box and RESELECT the option thats already there. Even if I want to see the other options I may open the drop down, but click off it when i realise the one I want is already selected.

Comment: 2GGG: no, tne first option must be used for clean up of an input beside, and it has some values by default

Comment: 2David: no, the cannot see the default, because its too small to see. they'll see once they click and dropdown appears.

Comment: 2Thomas: you are right, but Im not using it for submit. I use it as small dropdown menu of suggestions, once chosen then must **override** the values in an input box besides. The problem is that input box besides might already have some values entered by default, as they are stored in cookies and used for the query filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it. And I will proudly answer myself,

```
$('select.small').bind('focus click',function(){
    $(this).children().removeAttr('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from when the page loads then try calling the change method right after you set-up the change callback; this effectively acts as if the user chose it right away:

```
$('select.small').change(function() {
  //..
}).change();
```

Comment: It has nothing to with loading the page. everything that needs to be triggered is already triggered. That's not what I need.